# Function not reading and printing file content in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Hi guys im working on a school project which is an rpg game. I have created a load_game function which is supposed to go through a specific file, check if the file has the id the user enters and load that specific characters stats into global variables. 
The problem is that I made a function to print out the content of the file so the users can see their options but it doesnt print anything at all, I made a new_player function which fills the same file with new players and that works correctly. When i change a file to another one and write into that file manually it works. Here is the code:

```
void load_game()
{
    bool loading = true;
    do{
        ifstream in_stream("Players.txt");
        ofstream out_stream("Players.txt");
        cout << "      The last son of Allheaven                " << endl;
        cout << "+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+" << endl;
        char ch;
        in_stream.clear();
        in_stream.seekg(0, in_stream.beg);
        while (in_stream.get(ch))
        {
            cout << ch;
        }
        cout << "         Enter -1 to return to main menu                      " << endl;
        cout << "+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+" << endl;
        cout << endl << "Enter a number to access one of the above options: ";
        in_stream.clear();
        in_stream.seekg(0, in_stream.beg);
        int choice;
        cin >> choice;
        while (in_stream >> ID >> Name >> Class >> HP >> Mana >> ATK >> ability_dmg >> Defense >> magic_resist >> player_exp >> player_level)
        {
            if (choice == ID)
            {
                /*game_start();*/
                loading = false;
                break;
            }
            else if (choice == -1)
            {
                system("cls");
                main_menu();
            }
            else if (in_stream.eof())
            {
                in_stream.clear();
                in_stream.seekg(0, in_stream.beg);
                cout << endl << "Error! Invalid ID !" << endl;

            }
        }
        in_stream.close();
        out_stream.close();
    } while (loading);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A major problem is that you open the same file *twice*. Once for input, and once for output which will *truncate* the file if it exists. So when you create `out_stream` you will effectively remove all the data in the file.

If you want to read from and write to the same file either use `std::iofstream` to open it in read/write mode. With text files it's hard to edit data in the file though, so I rather recommend you open a temporary file for the output, and when done you rename the temporary file as the actual file.

Or in your case, why have the output file at all? You don't actually *use* it anywhere? All it does is truncating the file you want to read.

Comment: Thank you very much I was not aware that it truncates the files, I will give it a go to open it with iofstream and I hope it works.

Comment: @AlemTuzlak Are you supposed to *write* to the file in the same function? Then first of all the function is badly named, and you should also think about how you should write to the file, and where. If you're not supposed to write to the file in the function, then simply use the plain `ifstream`.